# SubScene in JavaFX does not show elements loaded from an FXML file

Tags: java, javafx

I have a program created with an FXML file (made in SceneBuilder) that has four SubScenes in it:

```
@FXML
public SubScene p1sub;
@FXML
public SubScene p2sub;
@FXML
public SubScene p3sub;
@FXML
public SubScene p4sub;
```

Each of these subscenes is nearly identical to the rest.

I can get the root node (which contains these) to show up just fine, but when I try to add the SubScenes, they don't show up.

```
//This is the code I use to initialize one of the four.
Parent root2a = null;
try {
    FXMLLoader loader2 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
        "PlayerConfigurationSubScreen.fxml"));
    root2a = (Parent) loader2.load();
} catch (Exception e) {
    /*code*/
}
/*code*/
if (root2a != null) {
    System.out.println("root2 isn't null");
    p1sub = new SubScene(root2a, 149, 260);
}
/*code*/
stage.show();
```

Any idea how to make them show up? I'm new at JavaFX.

Comment: I am a little confused. Does `PlayerConfigurationSubScreen.fxml` has all the 4 subscenes? If yes, what are you trying to achieve with `p1sub = new SubScene(root2a, 149, 260);` ?

Answer (score 2):

Set the subscene dimensions in fxml and instead of "new" just add the parent to the subscene.

....

```
p1sub.setRoot(root2a);
```

....

Answer (score 0):

I think you are approaching the problem the wrong way. From what I understand from your code, you want to load a subscene and then assign it to one of your predefined "slots".

This however will not work, as the pre-defined slots has nothing to do with what is actually rendered. Everything that is drawn in a window has to be assigned as child of a container of some kind.

I've made an example here that reproduces the problem you are facing:

```
public class ReplaceTest extends Application  {

    @FXML Button button;
    @FXML Label oldLabel;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load( getClass().getResource("ReplaceTest.fxml") );    
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static int i = 0;
    @FXML protected void simpleClick(ActionEvent e){
        Label newLabel = new Label("Hello! " + i++);

        oldLabel = newLabel;

        System.out.println("Nothing happens...");
    }
}
```

And the FXML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="replaceTest.ReplaceTest">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="oldLabel" text="TEXT TO BE REPLACED" />
      <Button fx:id="button" onAction="#simpleClick" text="Replace label" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets top="10.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

If you try this example, you will see that overwriting oldLabel does not affect the rendering window. Instead, you can try to create areas to which you add your new subscenes as children. This will update the rendering window and will (hopefully) produce the behavior you desire. Again, I've made an example you can consult:

```
public class ReplaceTest extends Application  {

    @FXML Button button;
    @FXML VBox wrappingBox;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load( getClass().getResource("ReplaceTest.fxml") );    
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static int i = 0;
    @FXML protected void simpleClick(ActionEvent e){
        Label newLabel = new Label("Hello! " + i++);

        wrappingBox.getChildren().clear();
        wrappingBox.getChildren().add(newLabel);

        System.out.println("Someting happens!");
    }
}
```

And the FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="replaceTest.ReplaceTest">
   <children>
      <VBox fx:id="wrappingBox" alignment="TOP_CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label text="TEXT TO BE REPLACED" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <Button fx:id="button" onAction="#simpleClick" text="Replace label" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets top="10.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```